# Equilibrium of autonomous first-order differential equation: ‎

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, stationary-point

Let 
‎$ ‎‎(\bar{x},‎\bar{y},‎\bar{z})‎‎‎‎ $‎
be an equilibrium of autonomous first-order differential equation:
‎\begin{equation}‎
‎\begin{cases}‎
‎\dot{x}=‎ f_1(x,y,z)‎‎‎,\\‎ 
‎\dot{y}=‎ ‎f_2(x,y,z)‎‎,  ‎\\‎ 
‎\dot{z}=‎ f_3(x,y,z)‎.
‎\end{cases}‎
‎\end{equation}‎
Is it possible to say that $‎(\bar{x},‎\bar{y},‎\bar{z})‎‎‎$ is unique equilibrium point of the following system:
‎\begin{equation}‎
‎\begin{cases}‎
‎\dot{x}=‎ f_1(x,y,z)-(x-‎\bar{x}‎),\\‎ 
‎\dot{y}=‎ ‎f_2(x,y,z)-(y-‎\bar{y}‎)‎‎,  ‎\\‎ 
‎\dot{z}=‎ f_3(x,y,z)-(z-‎\bar{z}‎)‎.
‎\end{cases}‎
‎\end{equation}‎

Comment: An equilibrium or fixed point is a vector $(\bar x,\bar y,\bar z)$ such that $f_1(\bar x,\bar y, \bar z)=f_2(\bar x,\bar y, \bar z)=f_3(\bar x,\bar y, \bar z)=0$. In other words, it is a constant solution of the differential equations.

Comment: Yes...Right....

Comment: The two systems indeed have the same equilibrium point $(\bar x,\bar y,\bar z)$. Anyway, they might have other equilibrium points, that differ.

Answer (score 0):

A point $x^*$ is called an equilibrium (stationary point/critical point) of a system of differential equations :

$$\vec{x}' = \vec{f}(x_1,\dots,x_n)$$

if $x^* \in \mathbb R^n$ is a vector, such :

$$\vec{f}(x^*_1,\dots,x^*_n)=0$$

For your specific example, letting the expressions :

$$\vec{x}' =\vec{F}(x_1,x_2,x_3)=\vec{f}(x_1,x_2,x_3) - (\vec{x}-{\vec{x^*}})$$

we have that :

$$\vec{F}(x_1,x_2,x_3)=\vec{f}(x^*_1,x^*_2,x^*_3)-(\vec{x^*}-\vec{x^*})=0$$

which means that $\vec{x^*}$ is indeed an equilibrium of the alternative system of differential equations that you mentioned.

Comment: Right... But can it be said that this is a unique equilibrium point?

Comment: @ma.h I see you just edited the question. No, it can not be said such thing. Take a simple example :

$$(x-1)(x+2) - (x-1)=0$$

Then indeed $x=1$ is a solution but also $x=-1$ is a solution, since : 

$$(x-1)(x+2) - (x-1)=0 \Rightarrow (x-1)(x+1) = 0 $$

Comment: Not if originally $f(x)=x-x^*$, as then $F(x)=0$.